# z-index not working on list elements?

Tags: html, css, list, z-index

http://jsfiddle.net/ineomod/8NeyY/embedded/result/

HTML:

```
<section id="diamonds">
<ul>
    <li>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="diamondImg" style="background:url(http://i979.photobucket.com/albums/ae280/ineomod/geak_zps76747320.jpg)"></div>
            <span class="diamondText">
                <div class="zoomIcon"></div>
                "Geak" Interactive Magazine
            </span>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="diamondImg" style="background:url(http://i979.photobucket.com/albums/ae280/ineomod/pink_zps8d76dfad.jpg)"></div>
            <span class="diamondText">
                <div class="zoomIcon"></div>
                "Pink" Magazine
            </span>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="diamondImg" style="background:url(http://i979.photobucket.com/albums/ae280/ineomod/f3_zps57ac8198.jpg)"></div>
            <span class="diamondText">
                <div class="zoomIcon"></div>
                F3 "Celebrate In Style" Ad Campaign
            </span>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="diamondImg" style="background:url(http://i979.photobucket.com/albums/ae280/ineomod/sgx_zps3a7e98c2.jpg)"></div>
            <span class="diamondText">
                <div class="zoomIcon"></div>
                SGX Infographic
            </span>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="diamondImg" style="background:url(http://i979.photobucket.com/albums/ae280/ineomod/namecard_zps6a64c3f5.jpg)"></div>
            <span class="diamondText">
                <div class="zoomIcon"></div>
                m:idea Namecards
            </span>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

CSS:
In the fiddle

I have this diamond gallery laid out as a list. There's a caption for each item. Hoever, I can't seem to use z-index to ensure that the caption stays above all the other li elements? It seems to be covered only by li elements that come after it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try giving

```
#diamonds li:hover {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

This will bring the only that `<li>` at top which is `:hover`

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8NeyY/7/)

Comment: well this should work since I was intending to let the captions appear on hover... but I don't quite understand why it only works on hover?

Answer (score 0):

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8NeyY/6/)**

It seems that you need to update z-index on every li element from higher to lower as follows

```
<li style="z-index: 4;">....</li>
<li style="z-index: 3;">....</li>
<li style="z-index: 2;">....</li>
<li style="z-index: 1;">....</li>
<li style="z-index: 0;">....</li>
```

here style inline tag is used only for demo purpose which is calculated by using jQuery